# Radius Nearest Neighbors - get number of neighbors in neighbors

Tags: knn, nearest-neighbor

I have coordinates. Each coordinates represent a building and gives number of resident. I would like to predict neighbors in radius 0.5km for any point. This point represents base stations. I want to calculate how many subscribers base station will cover. Anyway, I need number of neighbors in radius. According to my research, I found RadiusNearestNeighborsRegression technique. Bu this teqnique never give me the number of neighbors. It is only give the average value for all neighbors in radius. I need sum of neighbors output or number of neighbors. I will multiply average output and number of neighbors(thats gives me the total output for all neighbors.

I hope, I explained clearly.

Comment: Yes sure. I have more than 1million coordinates. I calculated 1M * 1M possibilities. That's means so many effort for my computer.

Comment: from geopy.distance import great_circle
from datetime import datetime

counter = 0
allResidents = list()
for x_1, y_1, _ in coordinatesPopulation:
    totalResident = 0
    for x_2, y_2, resident in coordinatesPopulation:
        if(abs(x_1 - x_2) > 0.005 or 
           abs(y_1 - y_2) > 0.005):
            continue
        
        distance = great_circle((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)).km
        if distance > 0.5:
            continue
        
        #totalResident += resident
        
    counter = counter + 1
    allResidents.append(totalResident)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could partition the residences into regions such that, if the minimum distance between any 2 regions is too large, there would be no need to make comparisons between any pair of residences split between the 2 regions.

Also, when you have found that A & B are close enough, A would count towards B's neighbors *and* B would count towards A's w/ having to repeat that calculation.